# Spring 4 resource properties file

Tags: spring-mvc, properties-file

**MyClass**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PIL_P_APPLCTN")
public class PIL_P_APPLCTN extends META_INF {

    @NotBlank
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "APPLCTN_CD")
    private String APPLCTN_CD;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "APPLCTN_ID")
    private String APPLCTN_ID;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "APPLCTN_DS")
    private String APPLCTN_DS;

    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer = 20, fraction = 0)
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU")
    private BigDecimal DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU;

}
```

**messages.properties** in **src/main/resources**

```
NotBlank.pil_p_applctn.APPLCTN_CD=Champ obligatoire !
NotBlank.pil_p_applctn.APPLCTN_ID=Champ obligatoire !
NotNull.pil_p_applctn.APPLCTN_DS=Champ obligatoire !
NotBlank.pil_p_applctn.DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU=Champ obligatoire !
Digits.pil_p_applctn.DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU=Seules les données numériques sont acceptées avec max 20 chiffres !
non.unique.APPLCTN_CD={0} existe déjà !
typeMismatch=Format invalide !
```

**AppConfig.class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.fussa.fyby")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {



    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

}
```

when i tried

```
messageSource.setBasename("classpath:/messages");
```

or

```
messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
```

this msg is diplay in console:

> WARN : org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource
>   - ResourceBundle [classpath:/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base  name classpath:/messages, locale fr_FR

so i think that `messageSource.setBasename("messages");` access to **messages.properties**.. but why on my jsp file the default messages are shown and not the ones in **messages.properties** !

Thanks for any advices..

Comment: Do a "test log", set a message entry and use `<spring:message code="label.test.message" />` to see if resources are loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by removing some custom messages from **messages.properties** and added it to **my entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PIL_P_APPLCTN")
public class PIL_P_APPLCTN extends META_INF {
    @NotBlank(message="Champ obligatoire !")
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, name = "APPLCTN_CD")
    private String APPLCTN_CD;

    @NotBlank(message="Champ obligatoire !")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "APPLCTN_ID")
    private String APPLCTN_ID;

    @NotBlank(message="Champ obligatoire !")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "APPLCTN_DS")
    private String APPLCTN_DS;

    @NotNull(message="Champ obligatoire !")
    @Digits(integer = 20, fraction = 0,message="Max 20 chiffres !")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU")
    private BigDecimal DECLG_IDNTFNT_NU;

    public PIL_P_APPLCTN() {
    }}
```

**messages.properties**

```
non.unique.APPLCTN_CD=" {0} " existe déjà !
typeMismatch=Format invalide !
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your locale is `fr_FR` , rename your file to `messages_fr.properties` this will allow spring to pick up the right file based on the chosen display languange.

Comment: @FuSsA make sure you use this `classpath:messages`

Comment: if i do that ..i got this warning :org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource - ResourceBundle [classpath:/messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name classpath:/messages, locale fr_FR